# Fetch CPU arch string in OS X (C, Cocoa)

Tags: c, cocoa, cpu

How do I fetch the CPU architecture string in OS X utilized either the standard C libraries or Cocoa?

Comment: I don't know C very well, but I'd run `uname -m` and get the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`uname(3)`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/uname.3.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/3/uname)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a cheating sort of way:

```
#if defined(__i386__)
    return "i386";
#elif defined(__x86_64__)
    return "x86-64";
#elif defined(__arm__)
    return "arm";
// etc...
#else
# error "Unknown architecture!"
#endif
```

It's not strictly necessary to check at runtime, as there's a separate executable image for each architecture.

Comment: Use of `__foo__` is not portable across different compilers by definition of identifier reserved for compiler or library use.

Comment: It works on gcc and clang, though, which is sufficient for most practical purposes on OS X.

Answer (score 0):

From `man 2 uname`:

```
   #include <sys/utsname.h>

   int uname(struct utsname *buf);

  uname()  returns  system  information in the structure pointed to by buf. 
  The utsname struct is defined in
   <sys/utsname.h>:

       struct utsname {
           char sysname[];    /* Operating system name (e.g., "Linux") */
           char nodename[];   /* Name within "some implementation-defined
                                 network" */
           char release[];    /* OS release (e.g., "2.6.28") */
           char version[];    /* OS version */
           char machine[];    /* Hardware identifier */
       };

   The length of the arrays in a struct utsname is unspecified;
   the fields  are  terminated  by  a null byte ('\0').
```

Hint:
uname -m returns `(struct utsname).machine`.